# Vb.net Sorting list

Tags: vb.net, list, sorting

and DN125I have a list with the following values:

```
   DN32
   DN100
   DN50
   DN80
   DN125
   DN65
```

I want to sort this list the following way:

```
DN125       
DN100
DN80     
DN65   
DN50   
DN32
```

I tried using:

```
list.sort()
list.reverse()
```

but this resulted in DN100 and DN125 ending up at the end of the list. so how can I sort this the way I want to?

Comment: You'll need a custom comparison that understands the ordering you require. See the [`Array.Sort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.7#System_Array_Sort_System_Array_System_Array_System_Collections_IComparer_) documentation.(the right overload will depend on the details of your array which you don't show).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the list contains strings, `List.Sort` will perform an alphanumeric sorting. You want to sort the first part alphabetically and the numerical part numerically, like windows explorer.

If this format is fix(first 2 letters are letters, rest is an integer) you could use this LINQ approach:

```
list = list.
    Select(Function(s) New With {.String = s, .Letters = s.Remove(2), .Number = Int32.Parse(s.Substring(2))}).
    OrderBy(Function(x) x.Letters).
    ThenBy(Function(x) x.Number).
    Select(Function(x) x.String).
    ToList()
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! Added a list.Reverse() to swap the order and now it is perfect.

Comment: @Fyer-Zero dont use reverse but OrderByDescending

Comment: That also works, saves me a line of code :)

Comment: @Flyer: it doesnt only save you a line. You can also use `ThenByDescending` if you want to sort the ltter part different to the number part. It's also more efficient because a `list.Sort` at the end would again sort the whole list, so the same procedure again.